# Convertir un char en QString como se hace?

Tags: qt

Hola quiero convertir un char en QString por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
QString s;
char a = "cadena"
```

Quiero convertir `a` en `QString` pero desconozco la manera de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

El código que has puesto es incorrecto. `"cadena"` no se puede almacenar en un `char`, sino que es necesario usar `char*`. Además, en C++ los arreglos así definidos son constantes por definición, luego la forma correcta de declararlo sería:

```
const char* a = "cadena";
```

Una vez solucionado este inconveniente, para insertar una cadena de estilo C en un `QString` puedes usar varias opciones:

```
// Operador de asignación
s = a;

// Constructor
QString s = a;

// Método append para añadir texto al final de la cadena
s.append(a);
```

Hay algunos métodos más que permiten trabajar con `char*`, deberías echar un vistazo a su documentación: [enlace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html) de la versión 4.8